# Slave error after master upgrade

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have two MySQL servers in replication (master -> slave).

I updated them with `apt-get upgrade`. It runs well on both except the I get some replication errors on slave now.

> Last_Errno: 1005 Last_Error: Error 'Can't create table
>   `performance_schema`.`cond_instances`
>
> (errno: 131 "Command not
>   supported by database")' on query.
>
> Default database: 'mysql'.
>
> Query:
>   'CREATE TABLE performance_schema.cond_instances(NAME VARCHAR(128) not
>   null,OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN BIGINT not null)ENGINE=PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'

Server versions are as below:

```
Master
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.62-0+deb8u1-log - (Debian)

Slave
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Debian 9.1
```

Comment: You dont have two different versions, but you have two different RDBMS products in the replication. I have serious doubts that you can replicate from a MySQL server to MariaDB

Comment: Yes I had the same thought :(

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure MySQL slave user is active and has the needed permission then check if MySQL OS user on the slave machine has the needed access.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by ignoring all the queries related to the table performance_schema.

Actually I think the issue was that a `mysql_upgrade` was missing. I found other issue a few request later which I solved by running `mysql_upgrade` on the slave.